# Universal URL for deep linking process | Android | iOs | Web

Tags: android, ios, web, deep-linking

I have a problem related to the deep linking process. I need to create a Universal URL and send it to the end users on their email address that should fulfill the following conditions.

1. If the email is open in an android phone then that link should open my app(with custom data) otherwise redirect to Play Store for installing my application.
2. If the email is open in an iOs phone then that link should open my app(with custom data) otherwise redirect to Apple iTunes Store for installing my application.
3. If the email is open in Web (Desktop browser) then that link should open my website with(a specific URL).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebase Dynamic Linking for this, see : 
[Firebase Dynamic Linking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIq42GpfO64AIVCIfVCh2cgA6tEAAYASAAEgKvEvD_BwE)